Questions about the color of Android Compose water ripples
I hope that the color of the water ripple after clicking will not have transparency. If I set this setting, the content will become lighter after clicking. Does anyone know how to solve it?
class NoAlphaRippleTheme(private val rippleColor: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color) : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor(): androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color = rippleColor

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
}

